# A double integral with singularity MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to perform a double integration of function as follows

[image]

I know how to write the double integral in MATLAB. As you can see this function is not very easy to compute due to that fact that the variables are at the denominator. Assume I call the integrad fun1.

I wrote the following code to solve it

```
gamma2min=@(gamma1)gamma1;

I= integral2(fun1,0,+inf,gamma2min,+inf);
```

I get the following error

Minimum step size reached near x = 0.160784. There may be a
singularity, or the tolerances may be too tight for this problem.

I also understand what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The singularity along gamma1=gamma2 looks very bad; the integral will diverge unless the function f is such that f(gamma1,gamma2)=0 whenever gamma1=gamma2. And even that may not be enough to save the integral. Can you specify the nature of f?

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab documentation says that "`integral2` performs best when singularities are on the integration boundary" [[src](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html#btdgcqq)].  Therefore, since your integration region is a simple rectangle over the gamma space, I'd break it into two regions about the singular point (`gamma1 == gamma2`) and sum:

```
I1 = integral2(fun1,    0     , gamma2min , gamma2min , +Inf);
I2 = integral2(fun1,gamma2min ,   +Inf    , gamma2min , +Inf);
I  = I1 + I2;
```

Comment: @George Yes, I meant `gamma2min` (apologies).  What you do you mena "it should be scalar"?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the equation you posted.  According to that equation, the integration region of `gamma2` runs from 0 to infinity (independent of `gamma1`) and `gamma1` is integrated from some lower limit to infinity.  If this is the case, all bounds should be numbers.

Comment: gamma1 runs from 0 to infinity while gamma2 runs from gamma2 to infinity... @TroyHaskin I will edit the equation above.

Comment: Understood. However, if the lower integration limit of `gamma2` is a constant, you can simply enter as one.  No need for a function handle.

Comment: but it is not a constant, the lower limit of gamma2 is gamma1 which is the first variable.

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case, what you are doing is correct since the singularity lies on the boundary (albeit, now it is a continuous line of singularities).  Since MATLAB reports that the integral still diverging, I'd go back to  Famous Blue Raincoat's comment on the OP concerning the nature of f.  If f doesn't go to `0` as fast as the denominator, the integral likely diverges.